# How to send link to current item workflow status page

Tags: designer-workflow, email, workflow-activity

I would like to send a WorkFlow email that includes a link to the current items WorkFlow status page - wrkstat.aspx , is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I found that referencing the current item Workflow column and returning the field as URL solves this. I then used this to create a URL and my problem was solved.